# People has 3 Addresses and Address belongs to People, what's the best practice?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, database-design, model

In mysql database with cakephp 2.4.3.
People always have 3 addresses.

1. registed address.
2. Where they live now.
3. Where they work.

Both tables are just like people timeline.(Mean the record increase overtime)
for example, if you change your name in real life. you will have to add new record in people table.
something like this for 1 person.

```
Year   name           address          address2      address3
2013 Parker boon   13/3 huston,usa  null         332/2 tansania
2014 Parker samel  13/3 huston,usa  23,NY,usa    332/2 tansania
2015 Parker samel  13/3 huston,usa  23,NY,usa    992 osky,russia
```

in 2013 parker boon lived at his regised address.
in 2014 he moved to 23,NY,usa.
in 2015 he works in russia.

I have 2 questions.

first, I made 3 foreign keys in People table(address_id,address2_id,address3_id)
and dedicated 3 Address id for just 1 people.
in People table.
people_id(PK), 
name ,
address_id(FK), 
address2_id(FK), 
address3_id(FK)

in Address table.
address_id(PK)  ,
address_name

Is it better than made 1 foreign key in Address table (people_id) ?
in People table.
people_id(PK) , 
name

in Address table.
address_id(PK) ,
address_name, 
people_id(FK) ,
address_type,
(registed,lived,work)

second, whether my method is bad or not. I want to know how to config model and 
saveAssociated() or save with transaction  in cakephp for learning.

[link to cake saveassociated](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)

Comment: what is they have two jobs? what if they live in one city in the winter and another in the summer?

Comment: if parker samel had change the address in winter and another in summer.just duplicate the record like this
2014  Parker samel  23,Ny,usa (for sumer)
2014  Parker samel  192,Ny,usa  (for winter)
I know its too many duplicated , but the requirement is to record everything what he did in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the relation should be as follow:-

1. User has one addesss.
2. An address belongs to user.

In address there should be fields as:-

year, user_id, name, address1, address2, address3 and is_active

if any address would be change you need to generate the new record with clone of last record and updated one with status active and deactive the previous record.

take an example.

if the user modified the address2 only---------

1. You'll copy the address1, and address3 from the last record and set the status as active for new record that you're going to insert.
2. Deactivate the last record.

Conclusion:-
At the one time only one record would be active so you can handle association with hasOne.
You'll able to manage the history of history change.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this, and the best would depend on your specific requirements for your app - we don't know enough now to say for sure.

But from what I can see, it sounds like you basically want to keep track of:
a) A person
b) A person's work address
c) A person's home address
d) changes to either a person's name, or a person's home or work address.
It sounds like the "registered address" is just their most recent previous home address.

I definitely would NOT be creating a new record in the people table when a person changes their name - they're not a new person; they're the same person with a different name. Likewise, with addresses, you don't necessarily want to create a new record when someone's address changes (you might - depends on your requirements).

One really simple way would be to have a people table, and a people_histories table.

The people table would store both the persons name, and the persons work and home address. And the people_histories table would just keep track of changes to any fields in your people table. A 'person' would have many 'person_histories', and each 'person_history' record would indicate the field that was changed, the date it was changes, and what value it previously held.

Another way would be to have people, people_histories, addresses, and address_histories, and a person has a work_address_id and a home_address_id.

Yet another way would be to say a person has_many addresses, and each address as a role, either 'work' or 'home', and a date indicating when the person moved to that address. A person may end up with eg. 10 work addresses, and you know that the current one is the most recently dated one.

Really, though, the best solution depends on what you want to do with people's previous names and addresses. If you just want to keep track of them for manual viewing, and they're not really a central part of the system, then a histories table keeps things simple, and works well.

Oh, and another thing, you should stick to CakePHP conventions, and name your primary key fields simply 'id'. And if you've got more than one foriegn key pointing to the same table, rather than naming them address1_id and address2_id, I'd name them descriptively, like home_address_id, and work_address_id.